# Domain Driven Design - Product Inventory, What should I do?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, domain-driven-design

I am modeling a common application that has products and stores.

A product can have a quantity in stock in n stores and a store can keep stock of various products.

That is, a relationship n to n:

[image]

In my model, both Product and Store are aggregate roots.

I can not relate how would this relationship in my class model using DDD.

The update of the stock would be done by Store or Product?

ProductInventory should be a new Aggregate root?

Comment: Not being 100% familiar with DDD, but is there a reason why Store should not be able to manage it's inventory?

Comment: Hi @XenoPuTtSs, there are no reason to.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the diagram you attached you are applying a relational paradigm. 
You mentioned three different concepts. First of all Product! In order for you to have stores, you have somehow to represent products in your computable model. What is Product? It is that thing you get from a manufacturer. Once it's built in a factory the product is ready to be sent to those who performed a purchase! So far we have a Product! Does it mean yet that it is "connected" to a store? Not at all. Why would you want to connect a product to a store? Talking with a better semantics, let's re-ask the question and say why would you want to have a product in your store? That's because you want to sell it! The Product abstraction has fulfilled its purpose! Now you need to represent a Product within the context of a store, and so you must use another abstraction to do that... what is a product in the context of a store? It's a ProductInSale or Publication! You have the Store that has a lot of products on sale and you know through the use of another cohesive abstraction the tracking of products, so you came up with a Stock new concept!

It's very important to focus on behaviour but let me resume more or less how it would be without specifying the methods of each aggregate:

```
Product {id}
ProductInSale {id, productId, storeId, price}
Store {id, name}
Stock {id, productId, quantity}
```

Hope it helps,
Sebastian.

Answer (score 0):

I could imagine that the Inventory is an aggregate root that has a list of Products as value objects whith all needed information. Products are an aggregate root perhaps in a different context. Changes must be communicated by events to the inventories so that they could react accordingly. For example making a product no longer available, should trigger an domain event "Product X no longer available" which should be handled by the inventories to delete the product (value object) out of their list.